# jQuery: intercepting out going link and adding parameters

Tags: jquery

When a user clicks a link on my page, I need to, before it gets actioned by the browser, add the param Hello=True to the url.

So, the user clicks MyPage.aspx in  and gets sent to MyPage.ASPX?Hello=True instead.

Has to be client side, preferably using jQuery

I can add an attribute to the  tags if needed.

Ian

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you need all links to be manipulated, use this:

```
$('a').each(function() {
  var href = this.href;
  if (href.indexOf('?') != -1) {
    href = href + '&Hello=True';
  }
  else {
    href = href + '?Hello=True';
  }
  $(this).attr('href', href);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing on our sites.  Works like a charm.  Of course, the link is changed BEFORE click...so that may not be what OP is looking for.

Comment: cleaner/shorter/better version:
$('a').each(function(){
  var sep = (href.indexOf('?') != -1) ? '&' : '?';
  $(this).attr('href', href + sep + 'Hello=True');
});

Comment: This breaks for #anchor links, as they require the anchor part to be at the end. URL ending /foo#mydiv?Hello=True is not valid, it should be /foo?Hello=True#mydiv.

Answer (score 11):

You can change all the links on your page like so:

```
$("a").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + '?Hello=True'));
});
```

If you want to redirect the user with those added parameters upon clicking a hyperlink use this:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href") + '?Hello=True';
});
```

Comment: But he wants to change URL without redirecting.

Comment: @sundowatch - the second example does exactly what he asked, "before it gets actioned by the browser, add the param Hello=True to the url". He means *before* the *current* href of the clicked link is followed, add parameters to it and redirect including the parameters.

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner/shorter/better version of @Jan Willem B's version:

```
$('a').each(function(){ 
    var sep = (this.href.indexOf('?') != -1) ? '&' : '?'; 
    $(this).attr('href', href + sep + 'Hello=True'); 
});
```

You could also place the statement in a single line, sacrificing readability:

```
$('a').each(function(){ 
    $(this).attr('href', href + ((this.href.indexOf('?')!=-1)?'&':'?') + 'Hello=True'); 
});
```

That's that

Answer (score 0):

I tried the cleaner version by @arnorhs and while it is cleaner and more compact there is a minor code omission as href should be this.href:

```
$('a').each(function(){ 
    var sep = (this.href.indexOf('?') != -1) ? '&' : '?'; 
    $(this).attr('href', this.href + sep + 'Hello=True'); 
});
```

and

```
$('a').each(function(){ 
    $(this).attr('href', this.href + ((this.href.indexOf('?')!=-1)?'&':'?') + 'Hello=True'); 
});
```

In a similar vein the more compact version commented in @Jan Willem B's post has this minor issue twice and should read:

```
$('a').each(function(){ var sep = (this.href.indexOf('?') != -1) ? '&' : '?'; $(this).attr('href', this.href + sep + 'Hello=True'); });
```

Otherwise both posts and comments look great and the (last) compact version works nicely (didn't test the others).

NOTE:  Due to a reputation points threshold I had to post vs. comment. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i tried to do to add parameter in the url which contain the specific character in the url.

```
[jsfiddle]: http://jsfiddle.net/nasabikram/prswd16k/2/
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't change URL with JavaScript without redirecting.

You can use `window.location=url;`

And also you may want to look this site : http://ajaxpatterns.org/Unique_URLs